# How do I use a variable inside my SQL query for Bigquery in Python?

Tags: python, sql, variables, google-bigquery

I am writing a function in python that is supposed to create a query for BigQuery to extract certain data. The objective of the function is to create a query that gets passed a userid. This query returns the data of all the tables that correspond to this userid. However, my problem is that I don't know how to make the userid variable? If I hardcode one specific userid my code works:

```
def user_id_data():
  query = """
  SELECT *
  FROM `name_of_the_place_in_BigQUery`
  WHERE userId = "1a2b3c4d"
return query_bigquery(query)
```

This code works, it passes the query to the function query_bigquery that then passes the query to the bigquery server and outputs all the data associated with the userid 1a2b3c4d.
Now what I would like to do is be able to change the userid that the query looks for without having to hardcode it everytime. I campe up with this:

```
def user_id_data(passed_id):
  query = """
  SELECT *
  FROM `name_of_the_place_in_BigQUery`
  WHERE userId = passed_id
return query_bigquery(query)

print(user_id_data("1a2b3c4d"))
```

However, this code is not working. I know that it is not working because the userid that is actually getting passed is passed_id and not the value 1a2b3c4d for which it stands (I know the explanation of the why is not great, but I am not looking for explanations on that). What I don't know is how I can fix this problem? Can I introduce a variable into the SQL statement? Than you for your help!!

Comment: Do you have full control over `passed_id` and are sure it is not coming from something like a user prompt? See: [Running parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: I used f""" and then put the variable in '{passed}'. I still dont quite understand the f, but it is working!

Comment: `f` is "A formatted string literal". You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). Basically it allows you to format a string and pass dynamic values at runtime - exactly what you're using it for! :)

Comment: While this may be a solution, it likely opens you up to a sql-injection attack if you are not in full control of `passed_id`

Comment: True. In my case, I have full control over passed_id, but out of interest: Do you have an idea how to do this in a way that is not open to SQL injection?